# Verify string presence in encrypted database

Tags: database, encryption

For a system I'm designing, I want to be able to verify whether a specific string is 'valid' or not, but I want to keep my database of 'valid' strings private.

I want to provide clients with a database of all valid strings, but this database is (one-way) encrypted. I'm reluctant to distributing a key to the client, since there are always ways to obtain that specific key from the assembly code of my program (I presume).

Clients must be able to enter strings into my program and it would return a boolean based on the presence of the string in my encrypted file.

More importantly, I want my program to easily check whether the string is in the file, but I want to prevent other programs from easily using (and/or reconstructing) the database.

I have formulated this a bit abstract, because I don't really know how my system will be looking yet, but I want to know whether something like this would be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for are cryptographic hash functions! MD5 and SHA1 are well known examples, but if you're building new code without strict performance constraints, SHA256 would be the one to chose, and if you're looking to make it *very* difficult to recover the original words, you might want to consider scrypt or bcrypt (although they aren't as popular and unlikely that your language will include them in the standard library).

Then your database can be as simple as an unordered set of hashes, something like (in Python):

```
>>> words = ["secret", "hidden"]
>>> db = set([hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest() for word in words])
>>> db
set(['2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b', 'e564b4081d7a9ea4b00dada53bdae70c99b87b6fce869f0c3dd4d2bfa1e53e1c'])
>>> def word_exists(word):
...     return hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest() in db
...
>>> word_exists("hello")
False
>>> word_exists("hidden")
True
```

Comment: I didn't really think about this, but the case at hand is a bit special, since the 'trade secrets' are actually file hashes. I want to prevent others from using my database, so I want to have some one-way function that others couldn't easily do themselves.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a one-way hash function that others couldn't easily do"? And you say that you want to prevent others from using the database… But presumably there are some people who are allowed to use it? At a social level, how would you distinguish between people who have access and people who don't? (would people with access use a password? A hardware token? An encrypted network connection?)

Comment: I want to be able to have my software program to easily check whether a specific hash is in the database, but want to make it hard to others (other programs) to use the same database. Legitimate access (through my program) should be possible, and the only feasible way to getting access.

Comment: Ah… Yes, That domain is called [white box cryptography](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bwyseur/research/wbc.php)… And regrettably there is basically no good way to do it. Fundamentally, you can encrypt the data, but at the end of the day you're always going to need some kind of key to decrypt it, and if you're doing that decryption in a hostile environment, it's impossible to avoid the chance that an attacker could steal that key.

Comment: There are a few tricks you can use to make it more difficult for the attacker to steal that key (for instance, involving licensing servers and so forth), but unless you can lock down the entire stack, you can't guarantee that they won't be able to compromise the key.

Comment: It might be more economical to consider including some [trap streets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_street), which will make it possible to detect when people have stolen your database, and help your lawyers prove it in court.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have something similar to PGP, where you can have multiple keys to encrypt a file? You can see that multiple keys exist, but not which keys exactly. If you can choose the keys as being the hashed values I wish to check and the file a single byte (or something else that doesn't matter), it would be unfeasible to at least extract the entire database. A successful decryption would indicate the presence of the hash, an unsuccessful decryption the absence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9202/discussion-between-david-wolever-and-ralphje)